# Change Width in table using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]

May I know how do I change the width of the above Bootstrap HTML table because the table seemed to be span across the browser screen?
Thank You.

```
 # here is where i embedded bootstrap into my html table
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

# i have use bootstrap here for the table design
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table, table table-striped">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

## this is a html code embedded with bootstrap without CSS style tags

Comment: Please include the code you have written so far. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DBS Hi i have added the codes

Comment: You can put your table in a `container`. `<div class="container">your responsive table here</div>`

Comment: @firatozcevahir how should i approach using container in bootstrap?

Comment: @firatozcevahir hi thank you it works now but may I know why container can change the width of the table, which spans across?

Comment: You can read the docs about the layout here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#containers

Comment: also remember to remove the comma and the duplicated `table` class at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```